# Modes of a Bimodal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I recently came across a problem in which I had to show that a discrete random variable $X$ has two modes $m_1$ and $m_2$. The information given was that $$\frac{P(X=n)}{P(X=n-1)} = \frac{0.9(n-1)}{n-3}$$

I need to show that this distribution has two modes, $m_1$ and $m_2$. My initial thoughts were to try and find the probability distribution, but could not do so from the data above. I don't really know how to approach this problem so any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that: $$\frac{P(X=21)}{P(X=20)}=\frac{0.9(21-1)}{21-3}=1$$ or equivalently: $$P(X=20)=P(X=21)$$

Now it remains to show that: $$n\notin\{20,21\}\implies P(X=n)<P(X=20)=P(X=21)$$

If $n\geq22$ then the RHS is less than $1$ so that $P(X=n-1)>P(X=n)$ implying that: $$P(X=21)>P(X=22)>P(X=23)>\cdots$$

If $n\leq20$ then the RHS exceeds $1$ so that $P(X=n)>P(X=n-1)$ implying that: $$P(X=20)>P(X=19)>P(X=18>\dots$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain why exactly you're letting the ratio of the probabilities to equal 1?

Comment: In your question you already mentioned the two modes $20$ and $21$. That made clear that $P(X=20)=P(X=21)$ so that the RHS should take value $1$ for $n=21$.

Comment: Is there a way to do it if you didn't know what the modes were because it wasn't given initially in the question... I added it in because I knew what the answers were. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @drhab Much more elegant than my solution!

Comment: The first thing to do then is to search for an $n$ that - by substitution - makes the RHS equal to $1$. Then you found an $n$ with $P(X=n)=P(X=n-1)$. That could do, but there is no guarantee. It might for instance be that the two modes are not consecutive. Further it is a matter of trying out. Also it depends on the complexity of the RHS. I think that in cases like yours you will always have probabilities $P(X=n)$ that will first monotonically grow by increasing $n$ and then will get smaller.

Comment: Sorry I still don't really get why $P(X = n)$ has to equal $P(X = n-1)$. Is there any significance to that?

Comment: If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are both modes then $P(X=m_1)=P(X=m_2)$. So if the modes are consecutive integers then some $n$ must exist with $P(X=n)=P(X=n-1)$. If you can find such $n$ and secondly can prove that $P(X=m)<P(X=n)$ for $m\notin\{n,n-1\}$ then you have shown that $n$ and $n-1$ are both modes of the distribution. That's what I did in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you so much I finally understand!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We have the recurrence
$$
\mathbb P(X=n) = \frac{9(n-1)}{10(n-3)}\mathbb P(X=n-1).\tag1
$$
Since probabilities cannot be negative, it follows that $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 3)=1$. Let $p_n=\mathbb P(X=n)$, then $$p_n = C\left(\frac59\right)^{3-n}2^{2-n}(n-2)(n-1) $$ for some constant $C$ (as can be verified by induction). Since $\sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n=1$, we have
$$
C = \left(\sum_{n=3}^\infty \left(\frac59\right)^{3-n}2^{2-n}(n-2)(n-1)\right)^{-1} = \frac1{1000},
$$
and hence
$$
p_n = \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{1458}\left(\frac9{10}\right)^n.
$$
Let $g(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{1458}\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^x$ for $x\geqslant 3$, then $g'(x)=0$ has approximate solution $20.4956$. Since $g''(20.4956)\approx-0.000158506<0$, it follows that this is a local maximum of $g$. So the integer values of $n$ that maximize $g$ are $20$ and $21$, with
$$
p_{20} = p_{21} = \frac{2851798070642983299}{100000000000000000000}\approx 0.028518.
$$